# UITextViewDataDetectorType Phone Number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have set the datadetectortype of textView as Phonenumber through xib. when i click on that number an actionsheet comes automatically from the bottom.In that action Sheet there are four buttons(Call,Add to contacts, copy, cancel).can any one tell me if i tap on call button in actionsheet then call will goes to that number automatically or which  delegate method will call if i tap on that?

Comment: I think you have to implement custom TextView to get the detectors touch. I guess, no delegate method in "TextView" that gives event of tapping the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no delegate for the UITextViewDataDetector.
The OS handles the responsibility for which type of DataDetector is selected and it is responsible for invoking the corresponding application and passes the url to that. You cant detect the action.